# "PG" class throwing java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: android

All of a sudden on Fabric I started getting a crash report with the below stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void Hv.a(java.lang.String, java.io.FileDescriptor, java.io.PrintWriter, java.lang.String[])"
   at ex.a + 42(PG:42)
   at Yw.a + 98(PG:98)
   at Yw.j + 2(PG:2)
   at Mw.b + 27(PG:27)
   at Mw.a + 1(PG:1)
   at ex.a + 28(PG:28)
   at cy.a + 4(PG:4)
   at Gy.a + 4(PG:4)
   at By.a + 20(PG:20)
   at Dy.d + 6(PG:6)
   at Cy.handleMessage + 51(PG:51)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 106(Handler.java:106)
   at VG.dispatchMessage + 1(PG:1)
   at android.os.Looper.loop + 164(Looper.java:164)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run + 65(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

The only thing I know is that this happens when the user in fragment that contains a WebView. The last release has been there for 2 months without a single problem and this suddenly pops up. I couldn't find any information on Google when investigating this and was hoping if anyone here has seen this before.

Comment: are you using minifier? disable it and show the full stacktrace

Comment: I have a very similar stack trace on fabric, started a few days ago. But mine has icu on the stack trace which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I have the same issue: Fatal Exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
abstract method "void Hv.a(java.lang.String, java.io.FileDescriptor, java.io.PrintWriter, java.lang.String[])"
ex.a (PG:42)
Yw.a (PG:98)
Yw.j (PG:2)
Mw.b (PG:27)
Mw.c (PG:1)
ex.c (PG:3)
cy.c (PG:2)
Gy.e (PG:15)
By.a (PG:16)
Dy.d (PG:6)
Cy.handleMessage (PG:51)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
VG.dispatchMessage (PG:1)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:201)
android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:65)

Comment: @casolorz That pretty much the same. Stack trace can be various depend on device and processor architecture. WebView's developers made different build for different processor architecture. So R8, which is using for obfuscation, made different class names for every build. But you can see that method signature is the same

Comment: reached the solution? I have the same problem, but only on android with api 28

Comment: @EdsonFilho all we can do is wait for them to release a fix

Comment: @PampaZiya I would like to know how you came to the conclusion that the problem is with Fabric, because I do not use it and had the same, exactly the same error messages, each line described in your problem.
I'm thinking it might not be Fabric!
I debugged through Android Studio, Logcat, and every detail of your mistake is mine!

Comment: @EdsonFilho i didn't say the problem is with Fabric, the problem with the Android System WebView. Check Alexandr's answer below for a link to chromium post where this issue is being discussed.

Answer (score 6):

There is the issue we created https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1003687&can=2&q=Android%20webview

That crash produces by System WebView (version 77.0.3865.73). So it's affecting only users who has System WebView instead of Chrome WebView.

Comment: Well that's messed up. In the past few days i got 315 crashes with 204 affected users...

Comment: And can you explain exactly how an application would be using a system webview instead of a chrome webview?

Comment: I don't know if that is the case in this crash but that situation is very common, custom roms and even some proper manufacturers will configure their rom to use the wrong WebView. Leads to crashes and other issues. You can actually check the webview package.

Comment: If the user has installed Chrome Browser then WebViewProvider will use Chrome WebView as default WebView. Otherwise System WebView will be used. You can check the WebView provider in the developer options (WebView implementation).

Comment: @AlexandrNevyantsev I've got the chrome browser installed but my Developer Options says Android System WebView and it's the only option there.

Comment: @PampaZiya I guess a manufacturer has been set Android System WebView as default. I think it can be fixed only with installation of custom firmware

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be less significant in the coming days:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1003687&can=2&q=Android%20webview

> Comment 33 by tobiasjs@chromium.org on Mon, Sep 23, 2019, 11:14 PM GMT+10 (a day ago)
>
> As of 4 days ago, 77.0.3865.92 is shipping to 50% of stable channel. Assuming no issues, will go to 100% today. You should already be seeing a reduction in crashes. (comment 31 suggests that might be the case).

Also looking at firebase/fabric there seems to be way less crashes happening since the 23rd.